# onload callback on image not called in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to preload image and set the height and width to a container.

The problem seems to be with caching in ie8 since it fails to load on subsequent refreshes.

I've looked up and tried multiple solutions but seems nothing is working, at least not consistently.

current Javascript:

```
    img = new Image();
    img.src = '/images/site/image.jpg';
    img.onload=function(){
        var width = img.width + 'px';
        var height = img.height + 'px';

        $('#container').css({'width':width,
                          'height':height
        });
    };
```

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You must set the `onload` callback before setting the `src`.

When the image is cached, the onload callback isn't called with your code as the `load` event is produced before the callback is set.

Do this :

```
img = new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    var width = img.width + 'px';
    var height = img.height + 'px';

    $('#container').css({'width':width,
                      'height':height
    });
};
img.src = '/images/site/image.jpg';
```

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer! Here I am wondering for the millionth time why code that works on every other browser doesn't work in IE. It does seem counter-intuitive to set the onload before setting the 'src', but that simple switch now makes my code work in IE8! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

This is how retarded ie7 and ie8 are, even after setting the src AFTER the onload event, the event listener still misses it.

Check this out, this is what I finally had to do for one of my projects - ready for this? Settimeout. Yup! That's how retarded you have to write your code to get things to "work" in ie.

```
myImage.onload = doSomething;

var slowMeDown = setTimeout(function(){
                      myImage.src = "img/somePic.jpg";
                 },300);
```

Un-freaking-believable....