# IE 6,7,8 don't support onload event in image object or DOM

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer, google-chrome, onload

My application has a large size of images to present and which should be resized for uniformly presentation with fixed width and height, to do so I write a JavaScript method in image's onload image like this:

```
var autoResizeImage = function(targetWidth, targetHeight, objImg) {
    if (0 >= targetWidth || 0 >= targetHeight) {
        // Ilegal parameters, just return.
        return;
    }

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = objImg.src;

    // Calculate the width and height immediately the image is loaded. 
    img.onload = function() {
        var hRatio;
        var wRatio;

        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;

        var calcWidth = width;
        var calcHeight = height;

        wRatio = targetWidth / width;
        hRatio = targetHeight / height;

        if (wRatio < hRatio) {
            calcHeight = targetHeight;
            calcWidth = (targetHeight / height) * width;
        } else {
            calcWidth = targetWidth;
            calcHeight = (targetWidth / width) * height;
        }

        objImg.width = calcWidth;
        objImg.height = calcHeight;
    };
};
```

HTML image:

```
<img src='PATH' onload='autoResizeImage(100, 100, this)'>
```

This way works well on Chrome and Firefox except IE 6,7,8. I'm suffering on this, how can I complete this task on IE 6,7,8.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Add the onload function before you set the source. Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429656/onload-callback-on-image-not-called-in-ie8)

Answer (score 1):

I would start by saying that if you're serving images to be displayed at a particular size, you should send them from the server at the correct size in the first place. Sending excessively large images and having the browser resize them is poor practice because it means that you're using up a lot more bandwidth than you need to. Your users may have restricted bandwidth, and may not appreciate the extra load time on your page caused by this.

However, I don't really know why you need to do this resizing exersise at all? HTML will by default scale an image to the size of the `<img>` tag that contains it anyway, so all you need to do is specify `height` and `width` styles for your `<img>` tag, and the scaling will be done automatically. There should be absolutely no need for all that messing around with Javascript.

```
<img src='PATH' style='width:100px; height:100px;'>
```

That should work in all browsers; no JS required. The image should be scaled for you.

But ideally, as I said, please try to avoid sending excessively large images to the page if you're not going to use them at full size.

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of assignments. First assign onload function and then src attribute. It works for IE 8 at least.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var text = document.createTextNode('loaded ' + img.src);
    div.appendChild(text);    
};
window.setTimeout(function() {
    var random = Math.random();
    img.src ="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/450989.png?random=" + random;
}, 1000);
div.appendChild(img);
```

```html
<div id="div"/>
```